# How to populate an object array using a Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to create a function which returns an array of Product objects from my Firebase database.

I attempted using a switch within the closure to set variables to their respective names, and then instantiate the object after all variables have been set. I tried to play around with the scope of the closure to try and access the "retrieved value". Below is a snapshot of my Firebase Database, my product object, and my function.

```swift
 func createArray() -> [Product] { 

        var newArray = [Product]()
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        var productName = String()
        var productHealth = String()
        var productPrice = 0
        var productImage = String()

        for bigIndex in 0..<7 {
            for smallIndex in 0..<4{
                ref.child("masterSheet/\(bigIndex)/\(smallIndex)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in let retrievedValue = snapshot.value}
                //I used to have a switch statement here that went like
                //switch smallIndex{ case 0: productPrice = retrievedValue as! String }

            }
            let completeProduct = Product(productName: productName, productHealth: productHealth, productPrice: productPrice, productImage: productImage)
            newArray.append(completeProduct)
        }
        return newArray
    }
```

Product Object:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Product {
    var productName: String
    var productHealth: String
    var productPrice: Int
    var productImage: String

    init(productName: String, productHealth: String, productPrice: Int, productImage: String ){
        self.productName = productName
        self.productHealth = productHealth
        self.productPrice = productPrice
        self.productImage = productImage

    }
}
```

My goal is to produce an array of all of the items in the Database.

Comment: [Firebase Snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/180dkLP.png). In addition, is this even the best way to get the data?

Comment: Unrelated but you are encouraged to remove the redundant property naming. According to the guidelines the names should be `name`, `health` etc.

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous so the `return newArray` will execute before the code in the Firebase closure runs. See the myriad of articles on working with Firebase data within the closure [Firebase is Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bswift%5DFirebase+is+asynchronous). Also, it's generally best not to call Firebase like a synchronous function and return a value. The pace of the application is set by your Firebase closures so leverage that - e.g. request data from Firebase, populate an array and then tableView.reloadData within the closure.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have read and discovered how to do it :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this is the solution that ended up working for me :)

```swift
var product: [Product] = []

ref = Database.database().reference()
databaseHandle = ref.child("masterSheet").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let rawData = snapshot.value as? [AnyObject] else { return } 

            for item in rawData {
                guard let itemArray = item as? [AnyObject] else { continue }

                var pro = Product()
                if itemArray.count > 0 {
                    pro.productName = itemArray[0] as? String
                }

                if itemArray.count > 1 {
                    pro.productHealth = itemArray[1] as? String
                }

                if itemArray.count > 2 {
                    pro.productPrice = itemArray[2] as? Int
                }

                if itemArray.count > 3 {
                    pro.productImage = itemArray[3] as? String
                }

                // if you use dict, do like this:
                //pro.productImage = itemArray["productImage"] as? String
                //pro.productPrice = itemArray["productPrice"] as? Int

                product.append(pro)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the value from smallIndex and set it into modelClass `Product` like this:

```
     func createArray() -> [Product] { 

            var newArray = [Product]()
            let ref = Database.database().reference()

            for bigIndex in 0..<7 {
                for smallIndex in 0..<4{
                    ref.child("masterSheet/\(bigIndex)/\(smallIndex)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in let retrievedValue = snapshot.value}
                    //I used to have a switch statement here that went like
                    //switch smallIndex{ case 0: productPrice = retrievedValue as! String 

          let singleProduct = Product()
          singleProduct.productName = "fetch value from small index"
          singleProduct.productPrice = retrievedValue  
          sigleProduct.productHealth = "fetch value from small index"


                newArray.append(singleProduct)

}

                }

            }
            return newArray
        }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The `return newArray` code will execute LONG before the array is populated from Firebase and will always return nil. Firebase snapshots are *only valid within the closure*.